# Find $f '(x)$ if $f(x)=\sin x$ by first principles

Tags: calculus, limits

**Question:**

> How to find the derivative of $f(x) = \sin x$, $f'(x)$, using the definition of derivative.

I have tried evaluating it but I reach a dead end every time.

This problem has had me grappling please help.

Comment: It may help if you provide some context--what are your thoughts on the matter? What have you tried? Where did you encounter this problem? Etc.

Comment: calculate $\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)$

Comment: You might need that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h} = 1$ and $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\cos h - 1}{h} = 0$.

Comment: Just to clarify: "by first principles" means "using the definition of the derivative", right? English isn't my first language, so I haven't heard this before.

Comment: Please list the first principles.

Comment: You should read this [thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $$\begin{align}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(x + h) - \sin x}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin x \cos h + \sin h \cos x - \sin x}{h} \\&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(\cos h - 1)}{h}\sin x + \frac{\sin h}{h} \cos x\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: How would we evaluate the limits of $(\cos h - 1)/h$ and $\sin h / h$? We can't use l'Hopital since we assume that we don't know that $(\cos h)' = - \sin h$ etc. We can't use a Taylor approximation since, again, we don't know the derivatives yet.

Comment: It can also be done geometrically. Just need to take a quick look up on the website here.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[\sin x] &=& \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin x}{h} \\
&=& \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x \cos h + \cos x \sin h-\sin x}{h} \\
&=& -\sin x\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos h}{h} + \cos x \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin h}{h} \\
&=& -\sin x \cdot 0 + \cos x \cdot 1 \\
&=& \cos x
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)=2 \sin \left(\frac{h}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{h}{2}+x\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be:

$$\begin{align*}
\sin'c = \lim_{x\to c} \frac{\sin x - \sin c}{x - c}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{2\sin\frac{x-c}2\cos\frac{x+c}2}{x-c} = \lim_{x\to c} \frac{\sin\frac{x-c}2}{\frac{x-c}2}\cdot\lim_{x\to c}\cos\frac{x+c}2= \cos c
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this counts, but:

$$\sin(x)=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dots+(-1)^k\dfrac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}+\dots$$

and:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=\dfrac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

which gives:

$$1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dots+(-1)^k\dfrac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\dots=\cos(x)$$